# Safari font-weight issue , text too bold

Tags: css, safari

When I apply a `font-weight:bold` style, the look of the font is too bold in Safari when compared to other browsers. I tried below css as suggested in some site but its still the same.

```css
text-shadow: #000000 0 0 0px;
```

Screenshots of text rendering:

**Chrome**
[image]

**Safari**
[image]

Here's my css declaration:

```css
p {

margin: 8px 5px 0 15px; 
color:#D8D2CE; 
font-size:11pt;  
letter-spacing:-1px; 
font-weight: bold;  
font-family: LektonRegular;  
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'LektonRegular';
src: url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url(myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.ttf)  format('truetype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-regular-webfont.svg#LektonRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: This issue is observed only in safari!

Comment: Did you get fix for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For rendering bold text consistently across browsers, your font should explicitly contain bold characters. Otherwise, browsers probably try to make bold variants of characters based on their normal variants, and results are inconsistent across browsers since they likely have different algorithms for such conversion.

Also note that text rendering may be different on different platforms on system level (e.g. Windows, macOS). Such differences are OK and do not typically need to be fixed.

See also a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296868) about `-webkit-font-smoothing` property.

Comment: It's true that not providing a bold variant of custom fonts will force the browser to generate a "faux bold" font for bold text, which may look slightly odd. But it will not solve the problem that Safari by default renders all text much fatter than other browsers - Paul's answer below will fix that.

Comment: @OlaTuvesson It's perfectly OK for pages to be rendered with OS default rendering. It's unneeded and even harmful to be controlled by web developer. Moreover, vendor-prefixed properties are subject to be removed or be changed in future, and therefore solutions based on them are not future-proof.

Comment: I really don't agree; most of my clients are very keen to maintain brand identity across _all_ platforms (as far as possible) - and yes, this includes fonts and their weight. Furthermore, the excessive bolding in Safari tends to make text harder to read and generally looks quite rubbish.

Comment: It's typical for clients to be detached from reality. It's up to web developer (or project manager) to explain different OS rendering specifics to client. Prefixed workarounds are dead-end road. And that has nothing to do with identity (logo is usually big enough to not be affected by cross-OS rendering differences even if the logo is vector instead of rasterized).

Answer (score 52):

Use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

The text-shadow trick doesn't work anymore.

Comment: thanks paul! .. tried the above css but can't seem to find any difference :|

Comment: This absolutely works in my experience. A million thanks and a thousand praises upon you and your house.

Comment: worked for me as well (on the div element, not in the @font-face)

Comment: @qxxx Just checking that you know that Safari for Windows has been officially dead for a couple of years now. There's no active development taking place on it. If you are using it to test your sites for Safari compatibility I'd advise against it. You'd be better off using something like browserstack ... or an actual mac :)

Comment: Even in 2022, it definitely helps a lot.

Answer (score 6):

The -webkit solutions won't work for the strong issue for many google fonts, custom fonts and fonts that don't have preset values.

The problem is that you need to specify the value of bold in the strong tags.

This can be done by two ways:

You can either include from Google Fonts or wherever your font is from in your header; it needs both the regular font and the bold font each should have a different font-weight number like 400 regular and 600 bold for example:

```
<link href="https://fonts.xxx.com/css?family=XXX:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or use the aboves source code and paste into your own css like below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'XXX';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('XXX SemiBold'), local('XXX-SemiBold'), 
  url...
}
```

Use whatever your font is instead of XXX.

Then also in strong `{font-weight:600;}`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was wondering why Mobile Safari was making the text extra bold when zoomed out fully, but not when pinch zoomed in. Adding the appropriate font-weight to font-face stopped it doing this.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here worked for me.  Possibly because I am using the windows version of Safari for testing.  I had to include the bold font in my CSS to fix the problem.  In the case of the original question he would need to add the following (notice it uses the same font-family name)

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'LektonRegular';
src: url('myfonts/lekton-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('myfonts/lekton-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url(myfonts/lekton-bold-webfont.ttf)  format('truetype'),
     url('myfonts/lekton-bold-webfont.svg#LektonRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
```

This worked in all browsers for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this particular issue. Actually any of above solutions dint work for me. So started checking the default webkit styles added by safari and found that *-webkit-text-stroke-width* was applied to body having value *0.5px*. I set it to *0!important* and solved the issue for me.