# -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased equivalent in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I'm using the **very** useful CSS property `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` in webkit browsers to ensure nice fine text on headlines etc. Is there an equivalent property in Firefox?

Font in WebKit with `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`:

[image]

Font in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see the text in Firefox is fatter than in Webkit. Without `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`, the text looks the same in Webkit as in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox sucks for type.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having a similar issue, apparently it's to do with sub-pixel rendering.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firefox 25+ (2013-10-29) supports a new macOS-only nonstandard CSS property [`-moz-osx-font-smoothing`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142) effectively similar to the WebKit’s `-webkit-font-smoothing`.

So this code should provide consistent results in Firefox and WebKit:

```css
.example {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;   /* Firefox */
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* WebKit  */
}
```

Comment: But this just works on MAC OS systems. This is pretty important to mention in my opinion.

Comment: @kwoxer
> new **Mac-OS-only** nonstandard CSS property

Answer (score 6):

Problem is `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`, which disable standard sub-pixel font smoothing.
Try read [this](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/)

Answer (score 1):

At one point firefox had a `font-smooth`, but it's been removed and as far as I know is not included at all in the current track.  I did some googling and didn't see any indication that there will be any change to that.

As an alternative you could try a workaround like: http://www.elfboy.com/blog/text-shadow_anti-aliasing/.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope you see what I mean now. Adding a Shadow here dose not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has the behavior you're after by default, as far as I know, so there's no need to request it explicitly...