# CSS Smooth font styling

Tags: css

I'm trying to copy the following font styling in my page:
https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/104117/screenshots/2080529/attachments/373853/real-pixels.png (scroll down to "typography")

I've tried the following:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #334455;
    background-color: #EEF2F4;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

All i'm achieving with this is this poor styling:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGzNV.png

I even feel like it's not the same font. Even more, the different font-weight I've tried never matched the one from the model... I have no idea where to go from here, can somebody enlight me on how to improve this?

Comment: What is your code for the text?

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/xhvwj9th/

Comment: What settings for the font rendering engine are you using?

Comment: It actually looks great on jsfiddle but on my localhost it isn't. I'm lost now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem you described in your comment once and I realised it was because my

```
@import url
```

was *after* the reset. I suggest you try the following:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was kinda worried i'd have to remove my css reset. That also explains why the jsfiddle was working and not my local version

Comment: Just to clarify: all @import rules must precede all other style rules. This is  by mandate of the W3C. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#at-import (I don't know why though; if anyone can explain...)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

> [-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased equivalent in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296868/webkit-font-smoothing-antialiased-equivalent-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS seems correct.
I tried the same with a dummy HTML page and it renders correctly:

```
<h2>Hello How are you?</h2>
<p>CSS Smooth font styling CSS Smooth font styling CSS Smooth font styling </p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhz1vm4v/1

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I had this soft reset at the beginning of my css file. After deleting it the rendering was good. I never thought it would have an influence on the way fonts are rendered.