# Safari font-weight issue, text is too bold

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I am using one custom font. When I use `font-weight: bold` it is getting more bold in Safari web browser, but everything works fine in all other web browsers.

I have tried the following, but none of them worked.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

and

```
text-shadow: #000000 0 0 0px;
```

Comment: What font are you using? Is it by chance a custom font?

Comment: @feddus He did state "custom font" in the question :)

Comment: @feddus I am using custom fonts that are generated by fontsquirrel.com. Thank u.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I was going to mention what ExtPro commented below. Maybe this thread can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450706/safari-font-weight-issue-text-too-bold

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a custom font this is likely happening because the font set doesn't proved a bold weight, which means your browser must synthesize it- this creates discrepancies between browser outputs.

This kind of behaviour can also be replicated if you try to use Tahoma or Lucida Grande with e.g. `font-style:italic:`, which neither font is supplied with.

If you're using Google webfonts (or other) you may want to check a bold version of the font is provided.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-yet-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers) on SO for additional information such a the use of `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`