# Bold font looks weird on Mac

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

Latest Chrome renders `Lato` differently on Windows and Mac.

Computed styles:

[image]

Results:

[image]

How do I fix Mac version to look better, as Win one? Thanks!

Comment: @IvanFrazaniuk This is [Duplicated]. See this [stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450706/safari-font-weight-issue-text-too-bold) and this [stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296868/webkit-font-smoothing-antialiased-equivalent-in-firefox)

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa both mentioned questions are about behavior in DIFFERENT BROWSERS.

Comment: @IvanFrazaniuk Chrome for Win and Chrome for Mac are different browsers. Try this from second link that i posted in first comment `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` that helped me for some earlier work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rendering bold text consistently across browsers, your font should explicitly contain bold characters.
Solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/9451858/1214162

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following instead:

```
font-weight:600 !important;
```

and see if the fonts match cross-platform.

Comment: Also I don't have enough rep to comment, what method are you using to include the font-family? @import, etc?